# error while im copmpiling Tor source code: "Could not find a linkable libevent"

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, cygwin, tor

I'm trying to compile Tor source code from windows environment with

> Cygwin64

- it works like the Linux

> Terminal

i'm downloading the source code from Tor website

https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en 
now, im trying to compile the source code(after a few changes that i made) with this commends `./configure && make` which works in Linux Terminal and supposed to work in Cygwin64. im having this error:

> WARNING: Could not find a linkable libevent.  If you have it installed somewhere unusual, you can specify an explicit path using --with-libevent-dir
>   configure: error: Missing libraries; unable to proceed.

Comment: have you installed `libevent-devel` package ?

Comment: No, i did not. i tried to find a way to install it on windows and i can't find a way to do that. can you help me with that? @matzeri Thank you!

Comment: For compiling on cygwin you need to install the needed development packages using cygwin setup https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

Comment: @matzeri Thank you, it's working!!